# Не могу включить в биос виртуализацию!

Tags: hyper-v

Около года назад настраивал виртуализацию, после чего её вырубил за ненадобностью. Сейчас же при включении опции в биосе спикер ПК сигналит о проблемах. Нагуглил, что проблема в винде, и надо её починить. Дочинился до того, что переустановил винду и поставил прошку. При включении виртуализации пищит спикер и всё то же самое. Я не знаю, что делать, помогите...

Comment: зайди в программы и компоненты и там установи hyper-V сам сегодня мучался

Comment: Включаю в биосе и всё то же самое

Comment: Если пищит спикер до начала загрузки винды, то винда здесь точно не причём. Ищите проблему в железе.

Comment: В общем, буду обновлять биос, пока что с этим так же проблема)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT IT! До обновления биоса дело не дошло, скорее всего это особенности моей системы, но всё же Опишу шаги которые привели меня к успеху:

1. Выключение Hyper-V
2. там же включаем платформу виртуальной машины и платформу низкоуровневой оболочки Win
3. Выходим в биос, в OC ставим експерт мод, включаем SVM Mode
4. Спикер всё так же будет пищать, нужно подождать 5 перезагрузок пк, после чего пк запустится и в диспетчере виртуализация будет включена!